# How to automatically run a transcompiler when a JS file is changed/saved

Tags: netbeans, ecmascript-6

I'm coding an ES6 project with WebStorm (trial) at the moment which has a tool called 'File Watchers', which also conveniently includes a Traceur watcher transcompiling ES6 files when they change.

Is there an equivalent functionality to the WebStorm 'File Watchers' tool incorporated into NetBeans?  Or a technique otherwise to execute a program when a source code file is changed/saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Grunt for such thing (daily NetBeans builds also have Gulp support). Define Grunt task that executes command (using [grunt exec](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec)) and setup file watcher using ([watch task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)) to invoke the exec task on file change

Comment: Grunting in NetBeans IDE (July 2014) https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/grunting_in_netbeans_ide